# Modify command line build arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, atl

When I look at the command line arguments (Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command line) of an existing program one of the arguments is

`/D "_ATL_STATIC_REGISTRY"`

How do I add this to my own project in visual studio?

MSDN shows an [example of ATL_STATIC_REGISTRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y3by0e2.aspx) using `#ifdef`. So I searched the codebase (CTRL + F) for the words "ATL_STATIC_REGISTRY" and came up with no results.  So then I searched for "ATL" and found these results:

#### stdafx.h

```
#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS      // some CString constructors will be explicit

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
```

This file with these includes exist in both projects.

Comment: _"but that does not exist in this codebase."_ What do you mean specifically?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Updated question

Comment: I haven't used Visual Studio for a long time but as far as I remember this can be set in `Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ >  Preprocessor Definitions`

Comment: @ichramm - I checked the original project (the one that has this in the command line) and I do not see anything related to ATL in there.  The settings are the same (except proj1 =windows app and proj2 = console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setting in Properties "Use of ATL: Static Link to ATL":

[image]